# Send SSL encrypted message to https server

Tags: sockets, https

I have a message already encrypted by the certificate of an https server (with its public key).
Should I send this message to the https server (I'm fine with any language) without being further encrypted.

the practical case is this:
1) on my server I create the encrypted message with the certificate https (eg google)
2) sending this message to a friend (eg via email) so that he can not "read" the content of the message
3) He should send this message (which is encrypted) to google, receive and read the answer.

Sorry for my English.
Thanks to all

---

I probably badly explained: I have two parameters to send with post method (p1, p2) to https server:

String parms = "p1=hello&p2=world";
this string has been encrypted with the public key of the certificate of a server https as below.

```
String encParms = encrpythWithCertificate (parms, "/tmp/localhost.localdomain.cer");
```

Now I have to send this string (encParms) to the https server that uses the same certificate.

So I have this code:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = .....
conn.setRequestProperty ("Content-Length", encParms.length ());
OutputStream outputStream = urlCon.getOutputStream ();
outputStream.write (encParms.toByteArray());
outputStream.close ();
```

If I send parms everything works. If I send encParms does not work. I guess the reason is that encParms is already encrypted, and then a "second encryption pass" to generate an incomprehensible message for the server.

My question is: how can I send the message encParms so that the https server receives the message correctly?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You may have an encrypted message, but you don't have an 'SSL-encrypted message', and if you hav a message encrypted by the server's public key, only the server can decrypt it. Google certainly can't, unless it originated the message in the first place, which isn't stated in your question. There is something seriously wrong with your procedure.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS (SSL layer, to be precise) provides transport-level security and encrypts the whole channel. It doesn't care about contents being transferred. There's generally no reason (in your scenario) to worry if the message is encrypted once more or not - double encryption doesn't significantly affect transfer speed. SSL does have NULL cipher suites which disable encryption, but as said this doesn't make sense in your case.